# Does this Fourier Legendre series inverting $\frac65\frac{x^x}{x+1}-\frac35$ diverge or it is a software issue past $\approx 25$ series terms?

Tags: convergence-divergence, fourier-series, graphing-functions, wolfram-alpha, legendre-functions

$\def\P{\operatorname P}$

The goal of the Fourier Legendre series is to find an exact explicit series solution to $x^x=x+1$, not just $x=a+b+c+\dots$ with unknown series coefficients. [Lagrange reversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem) was attempted, but it failed to converge each time or the series coefficients were not able to be evaluated.

To find the [Fourier Legendre $\P_n(x)$ series](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Fourier-LegendreSeries.html) solution of $\frac{x^x}{x+1}=1$, we transform $\frac{x^x}{x+1}$ so it contains the points $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$:

$$f(x)=\frac65\frac{(x+1)^{x+1}}{x+2}-\frac35$$ The solution of $\frac{x^x}{x+1}=1$ is the solution of $f(x-1)=\frac35$, so $x=1+f^{-1}\left(\frac35\right)\approx1.776775$. Now we find the Fourier Legendre expansion of $\begin{cases}f^{-1}(x)&0\le x\le 1\\0&-1\le x<0\end{cases}$ to avoid any singularities, [shown](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/d6okhlesrg) below:

[image]

The Fourier Legendre series usually has integration bounds of $\int_{-1}^1$, but we have integration bounds of $\int_0^1$ as we graphed $y=0$ for $-1\le x<0$:

$$f^{-1}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(n+\frac12\right)\P_n(x)\int_0^1 \P_n(t) f^{-1}(t)dt= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(n+\frac12\right)\P_n(x) a_n$$

Substituting $t\to f^{-1}(t)$ gives a [Stieltjes integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral):

$$a_n=\int_0^1 t\P_n\left(\frac65\frac{(t+1)^{t+1}}{t+2}-\frac35\right)\  d\left(\frac65\frac{(t+1)^{t+1}}{t+2}-\frac35\right)$$

Now expand $\P_n\left(\frac65\frac{(x+1)^{x+1}}{x+2}-\frac35\right)=\P_n\left(z-\frac35\right)$ as a Taylor series at $z_0=-\frac35$ to have a polynomial in $\frac65\frac{(t+1)^{t+1}}{t+2}$ via [Legendre $\P_n^k(x)$ expansion](https://functions.wolfram.com/Polynomials/LegendreP/06/01/01/0003/):

> $$\P_n(z)=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k \P_n^k(z_0)}{\left(1-z_0^2\right)^\frac2kk!}(z-z_0)^k$$

substitute $t\to t+1$ to get integration bounds of $\int_1^2$, and factor out the $\frac 65$ from $\frac 65\frac{t^t}{t+1}$:

$$a_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k\P_n^k\left(-\frac35\right)}{\left(1-\left(-\frac35\right)^2\right)^\frac k2k!}\left(\frac 65\right)^{k+1}\color{blue}{\int_1^2(t-1)\left(\frac{t^t}{t+1}\right)^kd \left(\frac{t^t}{t+1}\right)}\tag1$$

integrating by parts:

$$\color{blue}{\int_1^2(t-1)\left(\frac{t^t}{t+1}\right)^kd \left(\frac{t^t}{t+1}\right)}=\frac{\left(\frac43\right)^{k+1}}{k+1}-\frac1{k+1}\int_1^2\left(\frac{t^t}{t+1}\right)^{k+1}dt\tag2$$

$\int_1^2\left(\frac{t^t}{t+1}\right)^{k+1}dt$ requires another series and special functions, but that is not our focus for now. The problem is that multiple softwares fail past about the $26$th partial sum

**Wolfram Alpha**

At $n=26$, Wolfram Alpha starts [plotting](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotvariable%22%7D+-%3E%22x%22&assumption=%22FSelect%22+-%3E+%7B%7B%22Plot%22%7D%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotlowerrange%22%7D+-%3E%220%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C+%22plot%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotfunction%22%7D+-%3E%22sum%5BSum%5B%28%28-1%29%5Ek+LegendreP%5Bn%2C+k%2C+2%2C+-3%2F5%5D%29%2F+%28%281+-+%28-3%2F5%29%5E2%29%5E%28k%2F2%29+k%21%29+%28n%2B1%2F2%29+Legendrep%28n%2Cx%29Nintegrate%5Bt+%286%2F5+%28t%2B1%29%5E%28t%2B1%29%2F%28t%2B2%29%29%5Ek+D%5B6%2F5+%28t%2B1%29%5E%28t%2B1%29%2F%28t%2B2%29-3%2F5%2Ct%5D%2C%7Bt%2C0%2C1%7D%5D%2C%7Bk%2C0%2C26%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C0%2C26%7D%5D%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotupperrange%22%7D+-%3E%221%22) the Fourier Legendre series at stage $(1)$ like so:

[image]

integration by parts in the series coefficients, from $(2)$, slightly [reduces](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotvariable%22%7D+-%3E%22x%22&assumption=%22FSelect%22+-%3E+%7B%7B%22Plot%22%7D%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotlowerrange%22%7D+-%3E%220%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C+%22plot%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotfunction%22%7D+-%3E%22sum%5BSum%5B%28%28-1%29%5Ek+LegendreP%5Bn%2C+k%2C+2%2C+-3%2F5%5D%29%2F+%28%281+-+%28-3%2F5%29%5E2%29%5E%28k%2F2%29+k%21%29+%28n%2B1%2F2%29+Legendrep%28n%2Cx%29+%286%2F5%29%5E%28k%2B1%29%28%284%2F3%29%5E%28k%2B1%29%2F%28k%2B1%29-1%2F%28k%2B1%29+Nintegrate%5B%28t%5Et%2F%28t%2B1%29%29%5E%28k%2B1%29%2C%7Bt%2C1%2C2%7D%5D%29%2C%7Bk%2C0%2C26%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C0%2C26%7D%5D%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotupperrange%22%7D+-%3E%221%22) this effect:

[image]

shown at $n=26$. However, [plotting](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotvariable%22%7D+-%3E%22x%22&assumption=%22FSelect%22+-%3E+%7B%7B%22Plot%22%7D%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotlowerrange%22%7D+-%3E%220%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C+%22plot%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotfunction%22%7D+-%3E%22sum%5BSum%5B%28%28-1%29%5Ek+LegendreP%5Bn%2C+k%2C+2%2C+-3%2F5%5D%29%2F+%28%281+-+%28-3%2F5%29%5E2%29%5E%28k%2F2%29+k%21%29+%28n%2B1%2F2%29+Legendrep%28n%2Cx%29+%286%2F5%29%5E%28k%2B1%29%28%284%2F3%29%5E%28k%2B1%29%2F%28k%2B1%29-1%2F%28k%2B1%29+Nintegrate%5B%28t%5Et%2F%28t%2B1%29%29%5E%28k%2B1%29%2C%7Bt%2C1%2C2%7D%5D%29%2C%7Bk%2C0%2C25%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C0%2C25%7D%5D%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotupperrange%22%7D+-%3E%221%22) at $n=25$ of the same series gives a smooth curve as expected:

[image]

implying there is a calculation error starting around $n=26$. Maybe it is because $\int_0^1 \left(\frac{t^t}{t+1}\right)^{k+1}dt$, from $(2)$,  [grows](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Nintegrate%5Bt+%286%2F5+%28t%2B1%29%5E%28t%2B1%29%2F%28t%2B2%29%29%5E26+D%5B6%2F5+%28t%2B1%29%5E%28t%2B1%29%2F%28t%2B2%29-3%2F5%2Ct%5D%2C%7Bt%2C0%2C1%7D%5D) into the ten thousands for $k\approx 26$ and the plotting discrepancy appears. Conversely, the series itself may diverge.

**Mathematica (Wolfram Cloud)**

This section uses the expansion from stage $(1)$. Unfortunately, past $n=10$ terms, computation time runs out:

[image]

and when $x=\frac35$, the Fourier Legendre series should give $x-1=0.776775\dots$, but it converges incorrectly past $n=26$ just like Wolfram Alpha:

$$\left[\begin{matrix}n&\text{partial sum}\\24&0.771697\\25&0.780971\\26&0.780639\\27&1.26721\\28&-0.648316\\30&6.7218\end{matrix}\right]$$

[Mathematica notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/619d0d96-ddbf-4d92-be57-79831593469b)

Typing in `Sum[(n+1/2) LegendreP[n,3/5] NIntegrate[t LegendreP[n,(6/5 (t+1)^(t+1)/(t+2)-3/5)]  D[6/5 (t+1)^(t+1)/(t+2),t],{t,0,1}],{n,0,25}]` has convergence errors:

- “Nintegrate: Nintegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in t near {t} = <0.929672}. Nintegrate obtained 0.000539183 and 1.01235×10 integral and error estimates”
- “Nintegrate: Numerical integration converging too slowly: suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small”

The gradual convergence for $0\le n\le 26$ is expected, but the issue for $n>26$ is not. The series *seems* to diverge due to software errors, but does it really diverge?

Comment: If this series works, we can solve $x^x=x+1$ exactly albeit in a slightly complicated form.

Comment: Have you tried computing this with other software? Have you tried computing with greater decimal precision?

Comment: You can use create a [Wolfram Cloud](https://www.wolframcloud.com/) account and use Mathematica online. You would be wise to use [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/gp.html) to have an alternative for computation to compare. Both software have the ability to plot functions and use arbitrary precision which is almost certainly what you need to use in this situation.

Comment: You need to make clearer what it is you are trying to do mathematically. I am confused how using Fourier-Legendre solves $\frac{x^x}{x+1}=1.$ Please give more details about what you are trying to do here. Also why the $P_n^m(x)$ is needed.

Comment: You may get faster convergence if you expand $f^{-1}((x+1)/2)$ instead so there's no sharp corner in the domain.

Comment: You already have $x\approx 1.77677504$ for which you can get arbitrary close approximation using Mathematica `FindRoot[ x^x - x -1,{ x, 1.7}, WorkingPrecision->50]` . Why Fourier-Legendre?

Comment: Yes, there are many numerical techniques, even ones that give a series. For example, Let $f(x) = (2+x)^{2+x}-(4+x)$,  Then $f(-2+1.77677...) = -1.$ Expand $f^{-1}(x) = x/(3+\log(16)) + O(x^2)$ as a series and find $ f^{-1}(-1).$

Comment: @Somos Your series expansion has no explicitly defined series coefficients, but instead uses big $O$ notation. This post may give an explicit series solution, explicit series coefficients etc unlike the form you wrote.

Comment: You can use the [Lagrange inversion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem) to get explicit coefficients. For an example, the Wikipedia article finds the solution of $x^p-x+z = 0$ as an explicit series in $z$.

Comment: @Somos I tried Lagrange reversion/inversion multiple times, but it diverged or went to $0$ each time. For example, try $-1+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n!}\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}x^{nx}\right|_{x=-1}$. Also, series coefficients like $\lim_{x\to1}\frac{d^{n-1}} {dx^{n-1}}\left(\frac{x-1}{x^x+x-2}\right)^n$ are very complicated. The next best technique to get a series expansion is the Fourier Legendre series. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it, the problem is to solve $\, x^x = x+1 \,$ as an
explicit series. The question uses a Fourier-Legendre polynomial approximation method. I suggest another method. Define function
$$ f(x) := x^x - x - 1.$$
Notice that $\,f(1) = -1\,$ and $\,f(2) = 1.\,$ The root of the equation
is $\,x_0 \approx 1.776775\,$ where $\,f(x_0) = 0.\,$ Use
[Lagrange inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem)
to get $\,x_0 = f^{-1}(0).\,$ Invert the power series for $\,f(x)\,$
centered at $\,x=2\,$ to get

$$ f^{-1}(1\!-\!x)\!=\!2\!-\!\frac{1}{3\!+\!4t}x -\frac{3+4t+2t^2}{(3+4t)^3}x^2
-\frac{81+108t+228t^2+132t^3+32t^4}{6(3+4t)^5}x^3 - \dots $$

where $\,t:=\log(2).\,$ Apply this result for $\,x=1\,$ to get

$$ x_0 = f^{-1}(0) = 2 - \frac{1}{3+4t} -\frac{3+4t+2t^2}{(3+4t)^3}
-\frac{81+108t+228t^2+132t^3+32t^4}{6(3+4t)^5} - \dots $$

The rate of
[linear convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_convergence)
is $\,1/2$. The corresponding Mathematica code is

```
ClearAll[DP, M, f, x, x0, xn]; DP = 20; (* decimal digit precision *)
f[x_] := x^x - x - 1;
x0 = x/.FindRoot[f[x], {x, 2}, WorkingPrecision->DP][[1]];
dn[n_] := xn[n] - x0;
(* xn[M] = f^(-1)(0) with f^(-1)(x) series truncated *)
xn[M_Integer] := (xn[M] = Module[{pow, fx, t, iser, equ, un, sols, xt, gcd},
pow = (3 + 4*t)^(2*M-1);
fx = Series[ f[x], {x, 2, M}] /. Log[2] -> t;
iser = 2 - Sum[un[n]*(1-x)^n/(3 + 4*t)^(2*n-1), {n, M}];
equ = CoefficientList[Normal@Series[Normal@Simplify[iser/. x->fx], {x, 0, M}], x];
sols = Solve[MapThread[Equal, {Table[If[n==1,1,0], {n,0,M}], equ}], Array[un, M]];
xt = (List@@Normal@Simplify[Series[iser/.sols[[1]], {x, 1, M}]] /. x->0)*pow;
gcd = PolynomialGCD@@xt;
Expand@Total[xt/gcd]*gcd/pow /. t -> N[Log[2], DP]]) /;M>2;
x0
Table[{n, Round[dn[n]*10^9], N[dn[n]/dn[n-1], 5]}, {n, 4, 20}] //Column
(* 1.7767750400970546975 *)
(*
{
 {4, 1896983, 0.36981}
 {5, 738272, 0.38918}
 {6, 297928, 0.40355}
 {7, 123527, 0.41462}
 {8, 52303, 0.42341}
 {9, 22520, 0.43056}
 {10, 9829, 0.43649}
 {11, 4340, 0.44148}
 {12, 1934, 0.44574}
 {13, 869, 0.44942}
 {14, 393, 0.45264}
 {15, 179, 0.45547}
 {16, 82, 0.45797}
 {17, 38, 0.46021}
 {18, 17, 0.46223}
 {19, 8, 0.46405}
 {20, 4, 0.46570}
}
*)
```

Note that Mathematica had great difficulty with `InverseSeries[]` for
$n=17$ or above so I had to write my own code to do that for this case.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The “$\dots$” after the “$x_0=f^{-1}(0)=$“ indicate there is no expression for the series coefficients, besides something like $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}\left(\frac{x-a}{f(x)-f(a)}\right)^n$ and the [series reversion formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html) is too complicated to use. The Fourier Legendre series, if it does converge correctly, solves this issue by having coefficients that can be evaluated. This question is a bit obscure and the your method is computationally better than in the question, so you will likely get the bounty.

Answer (score -1):

$x^x/(x+1)$ is not an $L^2$ function on $(-1,1)$, it can not be expanded by Legendre polynomials. The singularity at -1 simply grows too fast.

Comment: Please see the edit explaining the derivation. The function expanded as a Fourier Legendre series is the inverse of $\frac65\frac{x^x}{x+1}-\frac35$, not just $\frac{x^x}{x+1}$, assuming the inverse is $0$ for $-1\le x<0$, so there are no singularities at $-1$

Comment: There can be a bunch of possible reasons,  it could be that an $L^2$ expansion need not converge pointwise or a.e.,  or it could be from quadrature formulas. You may first try to find out whether numerical computations of a_n are accurate, and then whether $a_n$ converges absolutely